# In magnetostatics, is there any relation between flux and current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, maxwell-equations

I have noted while trying to find analogy between electrostatics and magnetostatics, for the equation,

flux = charge/epsilon,

is there any corresponding equation in magnetostatics, relating magnetic flux, permeability and current. If not why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The EMF ($\varepsilon$) (which gives rise to a current) in a closed loop is related to the flux ($\phi$) through that loop by: $$ \varepsilon=-\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$ (The negative sign signifies that the current generated opposes the change in flux.)

The electric field linked to this flux circulates in the loop, and hence is non conservative. (contrary to the field produced by stationary charges.)

This is called Faraday's law, and the negative sign signifies Lenz's law.

**For a stationary magnetic field:**

$$\oint \vec B.\operatorname{dA}=0$$
This simply means that the net magnetic flux through a closed surface is always zero.
Applying the divergence theorem:
$$\nabla.\vec B=0$$

This zero divergence condition arises from the fact that magnetic fields always form closed loops with no start or end point. (i.e. there are no "source charges" for magnetic fields in classical Electromagnetism).

Comment: This is for time varying magnetic field right? My question was is there any direct analogy in stationary field.

Comment: Yes, edited it in.